# Update React front-end from .Net back-end

Tags: c#, reactjs, api, frontend, backend

I am recently approaching React and I was wondering how can I send from my ASP.NET back-end some updates to all the front-ends, but first let me explain myself.

I am sending some inputs from one front-end to the back-end. Just for reference here's how I do it:

Front-end

```
    async SendInput(data) {
            await fetch('Status/ChangeState', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
        }
```

Back-end

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class StatusController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("ChangeState")]
        public void ChangeState([FromBody] short i)
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Now what I need is keep all the connected users variables updated when this "state" is changed by one of them.

My first thought was to send repeatedly a POST or GET request to the back-end with `setInterval()`, but even if there are not so many users I still would prefer a method like Long polling or Server Sent Events.

What would a good recommended approach be? If possible include an example.

Comment: Have you considered using SignalR for this? Your scenario sounds excactly like a go to scenario for this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible state manager in my opinion for long polling can be created with a TaskCompletionSource. The controller waits for a state change with await and sends the result as ActionResult. The client opens the connection to this controller immediately after receiving the data.

However, I would only use this implementation for very small projects and is intended more as an illustrative example. For larger projects SignalR can be used.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Class for your state properties.
/// </summary>
public class State
{
    public string MyStateField1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string MyStateField2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

/// <summary>
/// StateManager
/// Register with
///     services.AddSingleton<StateManager<State>>();
/// in ConfigureServices().
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the managed state class.</typeparam>
public class StateManager<T> where T : new()
{
    private readonly T _state;
    private TaskCompletionSource<T> _taskCompletition = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    private readonly object _taskCompletitionLock = new object();

    public StateManager()
    {
        _state = new T();
    }

    public void ChangeState(Action<T> updateFunction)
    {
        lock (_taskCompletitionLock)
        {
            updateFunction(_state);
            _taskCompletition.SetResult(_state);
            _taskCompletition = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        }
    }

    public Task<T> GetChangedState() => _taskCompletition.Task;
}
```

**Register** in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<StateManager<State>>();
```

**Usage** (in your controller):

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> StateMonitor()
{
    var newState = await _stateManager.GetChangedState();
    return Ok(newState);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> SetNewState()
{
    _stateManager.ChangeState(state => state.MyStateField1 = "My changed State");
    return NoContentResult();
}
```